# How to create a number formatter at application level to format numbers based on different culture?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I am trying to format numbers based on **US base format**.

Code :

```
var data  = String.Format("{0:n" + 2 + "}", 7453215, new CultureInfo("en-US"));
```

[image]
**Output :**

```
74,53,215.00
```

Now the problem is I have this line of code at so many places where I am displaying numbers based on different culture so i have to change everwhere.

Is it possible to create some kind of formatter and register it once,change at one place and everywhere that change is applied to format numbers based on culture?

**Updated :**

```
var data = String.Format(new CultureInfo("en-US"), "{0:n" + 2 + "}", 7453215);
```

Now I am getting correctly formatted number as per US based format but I would like to create common number formatter at application level.

Comment: What exactly does this have to do with asp.net-mvc? And when you say _displaying numbers_, do you mean in a view?

Comment: @StephenMuecke Yes this is related to displaying in view and my project is an asp.net mvc application hence i have tagged this question with mvc tag

Comment: When I execute your code the result is 7,453,215.00, not 74,53,215.00 (is that a typo i your question?). And its not clear why you are using `.Format("{0:n" + 2 + "}",...)` instead of just `.Format("{0:n2}", ...)`. And is the culture the only thing you want to change

Comment: @StephenMuecke I have updated question with correct code and now getting number properly formatted as per US based format but I want to create number formatter at application level so if tomorrow if any body come and say i would like to format number in xyz culture so that i need to change culture at one place only and not all the place where i have used the code mention in my question

Comment: One option would be to define the culture in your settings file (or in `webconfig`) (say named myculture) and then instead of `new CultureInfo("en-US")` you would use `new CultureInfo("Properties.Settings.Default.myculture")`

Comment: @StephenMuecke So if i am setting culture in my web config file and then using string.format to format numbers so in that case i dont need to specify culture as it will automatically format my number based on web.config culture setting?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/183490/discussion-between-stephen-muecke-and-learning-overthinker-confused).